# how can i filtering data from Firebase rt-db using javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I need to print in console value of key temp but no things displayed

```
var database=firebase.database();

var ratingRef = firebase.database().ref("sensors/temp/");

ratingRef.orderByValue().on("value", function(data) {
   
   data.forEach(function(data) {
      console.log( data.val());
   });   
});
```

[image]

Comment: 1. Please provide a proof you actually are receiving the data. 

2. Check browser developer console to see if there are any errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need for using `orderByValue`. You have direct reference to the temp child so the `data` (which is a [DataSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.database.DataSnapshot)) contain the value of temp only.

```
var ratingRef = firebase.database().ref("sensors/temp");

ratingRef.on("value", function(data) {
   console.log(`Temp: ${data.val()}`)
});
```